# Basic example of create, read, update, delete with react hooks and firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

Most of the documentation I can find on React and Firebase does not use hooks. I was able to find a great example of Create and Read which I'll include below, but I haven't been able to find a simple example of Update and Delete using react hooks.

I am hoping someone could help me with the update and delete methods written in similar fashion to the code below.

CREATE

```
const useForm = initialValues => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);
    return [
        values,
        e => {
            setValues({
                ...values,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            });
        }
    ]
}
export default function InputForm() {
    const [values, handleChange] = useForm({ query: "" })
    function onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection("times")
            .add({
                time: values.query
            })
    }
    return (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <input name="query" value={values.query} onChange={handleChange}></input>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

READ

```
function useTimes() {
    const [times, setTimes] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection('times')
            .onSnapshot((snapshot) =>{
                const newTimes = snapshot.docs.map((doc)=>({
                    id: doc.id,
                    ...doc.data()
                }))
                setTimes(newTimes)
            })
            return ()=>unsubscribe() 
     }, [])
    return times
}
export default function TimesList() {
    const times = useTimes()
    return (
        <div>
            {times.map((i)=>
                <li key={i.id}>{i.time}</li>)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a `deleteStorage()` function. Of course you can put this right in your component if you want to.

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
const deleteStorage = (id, collection) => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection(collection)
      .doc(id)
      .delete()
}
export default deleteStorage
```

Then on the component I used it in I imported it.

`import deleteStorage from "../functions/deleteStorage"`

In the button I used it in (Font Awesome Trashcan) is where I used it.

```
<FaTrash
  className="trash"
  onClick={() => deleteStorage(item.id, "collectionName")}
/>
```

I'm still trying to figure out how to update. If I figure it out I'll post it here.